# How to alter and update an existing SQL table so that MULTIPLE colums can be added

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Earlier today I asked a question on this forum about how to add A column to an existing SQL table. I was informed that if I wanted to add A column to my existing table

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Aircraft (Type, EngineType, Speed)
      VALUES ('$type', '$engine', '$mph')";
```

that all I had to do was ALTER and UPDATE like this:

```
$sql = ("ALTER TABLE Aircraft ".
        "ADD COLUMN SubsonicORSupersonic VARCHAR(20) ".
        "AFTER Speed;")

$sql = ("UPDATE Aircraft ".
        "SET SubsonicORSupersonic = $mach; ")
```

But I have just realized that I have to add MULTIPLE columns to my existing table, not just A column. So I assumed that I do NOT have to include the AFTER function if I want to include multiple columns. What I did was

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE VisitNew
        ADD (COLUMN SubsonicORSupersonic VARCHAR (20),
             COLUMN ThrustToWeightRatio INT,
             COLUMN GroundAttackOrAirSuperiority VARCHAR (40);)"
```

and then

```
$sql = "UPDATE VisitNew
        SET (SubsonicORSupersonic = '$mach',
             ThrustToWeightRatio = '$thrweirat',
             GroundAttackOrAirSuperiority = '$groattairsup';)"
```

But when I try to run the commands (from a PHP file) I am given an error message relating to syntax. I have looked at various websites for a clue as to what I'm doing wrong, but no answers there. Could someone please help?

Comment: your semicolon in the alter table statement is before the closing brackets, same with the update statement. remove them and see what happens

Comment: -1 Tagging `mysql` and `sql-server`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use commas after `add`.  Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE VisitNew
      ADD COLUMN SubsonicORSupersonic VARCHAR(20),
      ADD COLUMN ThrustToWeightRatio INT,
      ADD COLUMN GroundAttackOrAirSuperiority VARCHAR(40);
```

Or, just use three `alter table` statements (if your table is not too big).

EDIT:

Similarly, the parentheses are not needed for the `update` either:

```
UPDATE VisitNew
    SET SubsonicORSupersonic = '$mach',
        ThrustToWeightRatio = '$thrweirat',
        GroundAttackOrAirSuperiority = '$groattairsup';
```

Answer (score 0):

Semi-colons (by default) mark the end of a statement. You've put them before the end of the statement which is causing problems.

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE VisitNew
      ADD (COLUMN SubsonicORSupersonic VARCHAR (20),
           COLUMN ThrustToWeightRatio INT,
           COLUMN GroundAttackOrAirSuperiority VARCHAR (40));"
```

and

```
   $sql = "UPDATE VisitNew
   SET SubsonicORSupersonic = '$mach',
        ThrustToWeightRatio = '$thrweirat',
        GroundAttackOrAirSuperiority = '$groattairsup';"
```

Comment: Oh, I see. THAT was the syntax error. Thank you kindly.